# Is it safe to share your `gitconfig`'s `user.signingkey` value with the world?

Tags: gnupg, git

I'd like to publish my `.gitconfig` file on GitHub, which includes a [signing key](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work).

As far as I understand, since this is related to code signing, the key referenced there is the ID of my private GPG key.

How safe is it to share it with the world?

Comment: I dont know about git and code signing. But as long as it is only the public key (or anything derived from it, e.g. a SHA fingerprint), its 100% safe.
Also, i think that setting should belong in your global gitconfig, not in a project-related one.

Comment: Thanks a lot @marstato. This is on my global `gitconfig`, which I was looking to publish as part of my "dot files".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is it safe to share your `gitconfig`'s `user.signingkey` value with the world?

Yes, that is safe.

The `signingkey` value is your GPG key ID (the lower 64 bits of the fingerprint) which is derived from your public key and does not carry any secret information. Therefore you can publish it to the same extent you would publish your public key. (Instead of the shorter key ID, you could also use the full fingerprint for the `signingkey` value.)